# Push characters of a string into the stack MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

May you show me what do they mean the last two lines of this code?
the Function "Stop". It should be:

```
move $t0, $0  # put the terminator of the string (Why in $t0?)

lw $v0, 4($a0) # I don't know
```

Thank you

```
Input: li $t1, 0  #counter=0
Loop: addiu $a0, $a0, -4 #allocate a word into the stack
      addiu $t1, $t1, 1 
      li $v0,12      #read the character
      syscall
      sw $v0, ($a0)  #write it into the stack
      bgt $t1, 256, Stop  #if the counter is greater than the space allocated into the stack Stop
      beq $v0, '\n', Stop

      j Loop

Stop: move $t0, $0
      lw $v0, 4($a0)
      jr $ra
```

Comment: That makes no sense. It should be `sw $0, 4($a0)`

Comment: But if the space allocated il  with 4($a0) isn't there an out of range?

Comment: *allocated is 256

Comment: Yeah well it may be out of range, that depends on how it was allocated (not shown). The `bgt $t1, 256` is already suspicious. Nevertheless, `$a0` grows down, so `4($a0)` is actually toward the valid region. Also note that `$a0` has already been decremented by `4`.

Comment: it was allocated by  "addiu $sp, $sp, -256"

Comment: That's already wrong because the loop uses 4 bytes (1 word) per iteration not 1. So you will run out of space way sooner. It's not clear what you want to do. If you just want to store a string, then you should use 1 byte per character and go up not down.

Comment: I used 4 bytes because I saved each character into the stack

Comment: That statement makes no sense. You allocated 256 bytes then used 256 words. That's wrong. Also, strings are usually 1 byte per character and go upwards in memory, no matter where they are (code doesn't typically know whether a particular string is on the stack or not).

Comment: But the register where I store the character and that I have to save in the stack is 4 bytes, so what I should do?

Comment: Use `sb` to store byte. Make sure you set `$a0` initially to the lowest allocated address and increment it by one.